# Shared config file among multiple web projects

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have multiple web projects each with its own web.config file.
These web projects have some common settings which I want to add in a separate config file say CommonSettings.Config

I tried adding a config file (as a linked item) as suggested in this post -
[How to share configuration files between projects](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/15/how-to-share-configuration-files-between-projects.aspx)

But because I already have web.config file in my projects,
run-time is looking only into web.config file and not in CommonSettings.config

Is there any possibility to add CommonSettings.Config as a shared file among all projects?

Thank you!

P.S. I don't want to add these settings in machine.config file.